# Can we write and read files on the disk using NW.JS in Construct 2?

Tags: operating-system, nwjs, construct-2

I am making a program on Construct 2 to write a file on the disk, and store it in an accessible location. After that I need to read it back. It is possible doing that using `Construct 2` & `NW.JS` in it? If yes, then do we have a sample `.capx` file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Website says Construct 2 is retired. Why are you building a new game with it? Use Construct 3.

This seems to explain how to use NW.js: https://www.construct.net/en/make-games/manuals/construct-3/plugin-reference/nw-js